# Get $concatArray result in single array without _id grouping?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which contains the arrays of similar kind of object. But they are in a nested element.
Output of `db.inventory.find().pretty();`

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "total" : {
        "sub_key1" : [
            {
                    "key1" : "1"
            },
            {
                    "key2" : "2"
            },
            {
                    "key3" : "3"
            }
        ],
        "sub_key2" : [
            {
                    "other_key1" : "4"
            },
            {
                    "other_key2" : "5"
            },
            {
                    "other_key3" : "6"
            },
            {
                    "other_key4" : "7"
            },
            {
                    "other_key5" : "8"
            },
            {
                    "other_key6" : "9"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "total" : {
        "sub_key1" : [
            {
                    "key4" : "10"
            },
            {
                    "key5" : "11"
            },
            {
                    "key6" : "12"
            }
        ],
        "sub_key2" : [
            {
                    "other_key7" : "13"
            },
            {
                    "other_key8" : "14"
            },
            {
                    "other_key9" : "15"
            },
            {
                    "other_key10" : "16"
            },
            {
                    "other_key11" : "17"
            },
            {
                    "other_key12" : "18"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "total" : {
        "sub_key1" : [
            {
                    "key7" : "19"
            },
            {
                    "key8" : "20"
            },
            {
                    "key9" : "21"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I wanted to page on the result of above collections sub-arrays, SO I aggregated them using :

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        total: {
            $concatArrays:[ 
                { $ifNull: ["$total.sub_key1", []]},
                { $ifNull: ["$total.sub_key2", []]}
            ]
        }
    } }
]).pretty();
```

Result as below:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "total" : [
            {
                    "key1" : "1"
            },
            {
                    "key2" : "2"
            },
            {
                    "key3" : "3"
            },
            {
                    "other_key1" : "4"
            },
            {
                    "other_key2" : "5"
            },
            {
                    "other_key3" : "6"
            },
            {
                    "other_key4" : "7"
            },
            {
                    "other_key5" : "8"
            },
            {
                    "other_key6" : "9"
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "insights" : [
        {
                "key4" : "10"
        },
        {
                "key5" : "11"
        },
        {
                "key6" : "12"
        },
        {
                "other_key7" : "13"
        },
        {
                "other_key8" : "14"
        },
        {
                "other_key9" : "15"
        },
        {
                "other_key10" : "16"
        },
        {
                "other_key11" : "17"
        },
        {
                "other_key12" : "18"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "insights" : [
        {
                "key7" : "19"
        },
        {
                "key8" : "20"
        },
        {
                "key9" : "21"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I wanted the result in a single array :

```
{
  "total": [
    {
      "key1": "1"
    },
    {
      "key2": "2"
    },
    {
      "key3": "3"
    },
    {
      "other_key1": "4"
    },
    {
      "other_key2": "5"
    },
    {
      "other_key3": "6"
    },
    {
      "other_key4": "7"
    },
    {
      "other_key5": "8"
    },
    {
      "other_key6": "9"
    },
    {
      "key4": "10"
    },
    {
      "key5": "11"
    },
    {
      "key6": "12"
    },
    {
      "other_key7": "13"
    },
    {
      "other_key8": "14"
    },
    {
      "other_key9": "15"
    },
    {
      "other_key10": "16"
    },
    {
      "other_key11": "17"
    },
    {
      "other_key12": "18"
    },
    {
      "key7": "19"
    },
    {
      "key8": "20"
    },
    {
      "key9": "21"
    }
  ]
}
```

But without the `$project` the `$concatArrays` gives error:

```
db.inventory.aggregate({
    $concatArrays:[ 
        { $ifNull: ["$total.sub_key1", []]},
        {$ifNull: ["$total.sub_key2", []]}
    ]}).pretty();

"errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$concatArrays'"
```

Is there another alternative for use of $concatArray which will just output the aggregated array out of all the collection documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `$concatArrays` you need to put it into the `$project` pipeline otherwise mongoDB will not recognize `$concatArrays` as it is not an pipeline stage of mongoDB.

Try this query, after adding `$unwind` and `$group` stage it might solve your problem:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      total: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$total.sub_key1",
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$total.sub_key2",
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$total"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: {
        $push: "$total"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you want to remove the `_id` field after grouping you need to add an extra `$project` pipeline.